# React filter from lists of locations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of locations that shows when the textfield onfocus, what i want is when the user type in the textfield it will filter or search in the locations. I have successfully showing the lists of location, the problem i have is the filtering or search within the lists of locations

```
const propTypes = {
  locations: PropTypes.array,
  setActiveLocation: PropTypes.func,
  setViewLocationList: PropTypes.func,
  startSearch: PropTypes.func,
  viewLocationList: PropTypes.bool,
};
const defaultProps = {
  locations: [],
  setActiveLocation: () => {},
  setViewLocationList: () => {

  },
  startSearch: () => {},
  viewLocationList: false,
};

const LocationSearchWidget = ({
  locations,
  viewLocationList,
  setViewLocationList,
  setActiveLocation,
  startSearch,
}) => {
  const [searchParameter, setSearchParameter] = useState("");
  const onChangeLocation = (event) => {
    setSearchParameter(event.target.value)
    locations.filter(l => l.name === searchParameter).map(filteredLocation => (
      location = filteredLocation
    ))
  };
  return (
    <div className="widget-container">
      <Box
        component="form"
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        className="filter-container"
      >
        <TextField
          size="small"
          fullWidth
          name="locationName"
          onChange={onChangeLocation}
          variant="standard"
          placeholder="Search Locations"
          onFocus={openSearch}
          value={searchParameter}
     
          }}
        />
      </Box>
      <Collapse in={viewLocationList} sx={{ my: '2px' }}>
        <Box className="rounded-scrollbar widget-result-container">
          {locations.map((location, index) => (
            <LocationWidgetItem
              key={index}
              location={location}
              onClickLocation={setActiveLocation}
            />
          ))}
        </Box>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy is to keep the text from the input on state, then simply filter the locations list before using it.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const onChangeLocation = (event) => setInput(event.target.value); 

// Then later
{locations.filter(l => l.name === input).map(...)}
```

Comment: where should i put the filter? inside the onchange?

Answer (score -1):

The problem here ...

```
locations.filter(location.name == event.target.value(filteredLocation => (
      console.log(filteredLocation)
    )))
```

`filter` function will return a value
you can use `forEach` Function

you can try this

```
locations.forEach((location)=>{
if(location.name == event.target.value){
console.log(location)
}
});
```

Comment: it doesnt work sir